# Reshape the input of fully connected layer in a tensor flow code?

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code I have 2 maximum pooling and 2 convolutional layer. After pooling_out2 I want to add a fully connected layer.
If I mention

```
`W-input=tf.reshape(pooling_out2, [-1,FLAGS.image_size*FLAGS.image_size*32])`
```

it will pick-up initial value of image.Let's say I started with image size 28. What command should I give that it reshape the dimension of pooling_out2?

```
    `batch_size = 4
     input =     tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([batch_size,FLAGS.image_size,FLAGS.image_size,FLAGS.input_channel]))
    filter = weight_variable([FLAGS.image_size,FLAGS.image_size,FLAGS.input_channel,FLAGS.filter_channel])
    filter_2= 
 weight_variable([FLAGS.filter_size,FLAGS.filter_size,FLAGS.filter_channel,32])
    def conv2d(inputs,filters):
        return tf.nn.conv2d(inputs,filters,strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
    def max_pool(conv_out):
        return tf.nn.max_pool(conv_out,ksize=[1,FLAGS.filter_size,FLAGS.filter_size,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')
    conv_out1 = conv2d(input,filter)
    pooling_out1 = max_pool(conv_out1)
    conv_out2 = conv2d(pooling_out1,filter_2)
    pooling_out2 = max_pool(conv_out2)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the shape of a tensorflow tensor (as a tensorflow tensor) with the command tf.shape

Then it should be sufficient to multiply the dimensions after the first one, something like this:

```
last_shape = tf.shape(pooling_out2)
n_features = tf.reduce_prod(last_shape[1:])
new_shape = [last_shape[0], n_features]
W_input = tf.reshape(pooling_out2, new_shape)
```